# CAS Single logout not working

Tags: java, single-sign-on, cas

I am implementing Single-Sign-On + Single-Log-Out in a Java EE environment through CAS.

On the authentication side I have the cas-server-webapp v4.0.1. Then 2 simple Java + Spring MVC web apps with the `cas-client-corev3.1.10`.

No issues regarding single sign on. If I access /app1 I'm redirected to cas login page in cas-server-webapp. After the user+pass input I get redirected to /app1 correctly authenticated. In addition, if I navigate to /app2, this one gets its auth ticket. So far so good.

As for single logout, maybe I have misunderstood the **[doc](http://jasig.github.io/cas/development/installation/Logout-Single-Signout.html)**: but this is what I do:

app1 and app2 have each a Spring controller mapped for /logout url:

```
@Controller
public class LogoutController {

    @RequestMapping("/logout")
    public String logout(HttpSession session){
        session.invalidate();
        return "redirect:https://cas-server-host:8443/cas/logout?service=http://cas-server-host:9080/cas1/action/index";
    }
}
```

That is to say, I invalidate the http session and redirect to the cas server logout url so that the tickets get invalidated.

In the cas server log I see that it destroys the TGT ticket and sends a logout request to the CAS filter of each app:

```
DEBUG [org.jasig.cas.CentralAuthenticationServiceImpl] - <Removing ticket [TGT-9-inxrphuRfIFpkbPTvNf6v1bAx7RlR7IMeMUFU0aokNCdbZ43Ij-cas01.example.org] from registry.>
DEBUG [org.jasig.cas.ticket.registry.DefaultTicketRegistry] - <Attempting to retrieve ticket [TGT-9-inxrphuRfIFpkbPTvNf6v1bAx7RlR7IMeMUFU0aokNCdbZ43Ij-cas01.example.org]>
DEBUG [org.jasig.cas.ticket.registry.DefaultTicketRegistry] - <Ticket [TGT-9-inxrphuRfIFpkbPTvNf6v1bAx7RlR7IMeMUFU0aokNCdbZ43Ij-cas01.example.org] found in registry.>
DEBUG [org.jasig.cas.CentralAuthenticationServiceImpl] - <Ticket found. Processing logout requests and then deleting the ticket...>
DEBUG [org.jasig.cas.logout.SamlCompliantLogoutMessageCreator] - <Generated logout message: [<samlp:LogoutRequest xmlns:samlp="urn:oasis:names:tc:SAML:2.0:protocol" ID="LR-13-TfRj1HnvAjpBjNIdaDvDMJUMXk7wffdXgB5" Version="2.0" IssueInstant="2015-02-10T12:18:18Z"><saml:NameID xmlns:saml="urn:oasis:names:tc:SAML:2.0:assertion">@NOT_USED@</saml:NameID><samlp:SessionIndex>ST-16-aXpUJpwO4MQ09caXZRKX-cas01.example.org</samlp:SessionIndex></samlp:LogoutRequest>]>
DEBUG [org.jasig.cas.logout.LogoutManagerImpl] - <Sending logout request for: [http://localhost:9080/cas2]>
DEBUG [org.jasig.cas.util.SimpleHttpClient] - <Attempting to access http://localhost:9080/cas2>
DEBUG [org.jasig.cas.logout.SamlCompliantLogoutMessageCreator] - <Generated logout message: [<samlp:LogoutRequest xmlns:samlp="urn:oasis:names:tc:SAML:2.0:protocol" ID="LR-14-BaKvuaIbwxg9Le9H3QIvWORfNSE0dxaxsCE" Version="2.0" IssueInstant="2015-02-10T12:18:20Z"><saml:NameID xmlns:saml="urn:oasis:names:tc:SAML:2.0:assertion">@NOT_USED@</saml:NameID><samlp:SessionIndex>ST-15-zaX6aojKs0PiggCles6J-cas01.example.org</samlp:SessionIndex></samlp:LogoutRequest>]>
DEBUG [org.jasig.cas.util.SimpleHttpClient] - <Finished sending message to http://localhost:9080/cas2>
DEBUG [org.jasig.cas.logout.LogoutManagerImpl] - <Sending logout request for: [http://localhost:9080/cas1]>
DEBUG [org.jasig.cas.ticket.registry.DefaultTicketRegistry] - <Removing ticket [TGT-9-inxrphuRfIFpkbPTvNf6v1bAx7RlR7IMeMUFU0aokNCdbZ43Ij-cas01.example.org] from registry>
DEBUG [org.jasig.cas.ticket.registry.DefaultTicketRegistry] - <Attempting to retrieve ticket [TGT-9-inxrphuRfIFpkbPTvNf6v1bAx7RlR7IMeMUFU0aokNCdbZ43Ij-cas01.example.org]>
DEBUG [org.jasig.cas.util.SimpleHttpClient] - <Attempting to access http://localhost:9080/cas1>
INFO [com.github.inspektr.audit.support.Slf4jLoggingAuditTrailManager] - <Audit trail record BEGIN
=============================================================
WHO: audit:unknown
WHAT: TGT-9-inxrphuRfIFpkbPTvNf6v1bAx7RlR7IMeMUFU0aokNCdbZ43Ij-cas01.example.org
ACTION: TICKET_GRANTING_TICKET_DESTROYED
APPLICATION: CAS
WHEN: Tue Feb 10 12:18:20 CET 2015
CLIENT IP ADDRESS: 192.168.13.164
SERVER IP ADDRESS: 192.168.13.164
=============================================================
```

Now, suppose that I logged out from /cas1, I am sent back to the cas-server login page. Without login again, if I access /app2, **I am allowed to navigated this app as if I were still authenticated** and I can access both its java.user.Principal and session. How can this be possible? Shouldn't the logout request received in /app2 have destroyed the Principal and http session?

Comment: Can you please share your deployerConfigContext.xml?

Comment: may you show me your application service json file. and please mention the external dependency added for CAS client.

Answer (score 5, accepted):

...my fault, as expected I was missing something. I had to include the Single Sign Out Filter and Listener in both apps :

```
    <filter>   
        <filter-name>CAS Single Sign Out Filter</filter-name>   
        <filter-class>org.jasig.cas.client.session.SingleSignOutFilter
        </filter-class>
    </filter>
    <filter-mapping>   
        <filter-name>CAS Single Sign Out Filter</filter-name>   
        <url-pattern>/*</url-pattern></filter-mapping>
    <listener>    
        <listener-class>org.jasig.cas.client.session.SingleSignOutHttpSessionListener</listener-class>
    </listener>

    <filter>  
        <filter-name>CAS Authentication Filter</filter-name>  
        <filter-class>org.jasig.cas.client.authentication.AuthenticationFilter</filter-class>  
        <init-param>  
            <param-name>casServerLoginUrl</param-name>  
            <param-value>https://cas-server-host:8443/cas/login</param-value>  
        </init-param>  
        <init-param>  
            <param-name>service</param-name>  
            <param-value>http://localhost:9080/cas1</param-value>  
        </init-param>  
    </filter>
     <filter-mapping>  
        <filter-name>CAS Authentication Filter</filter-name>  
        <url-pattern>/*</url-pattern>  
    </filter-mapping>  

    <filter>  
        <filter-name>CAS Validation Filter</filter-name>  
        <filter-class>org.jasig.cas.client.validation.Cas20ProxyReceivingTicketValidationFilter</filter-class>  
        <init-param>  
            <param-name>casServerUrlPrefix</param-name>  
            <param-value>https://cas-server-host:8443/cas/</param-value>  
        </init-param>  
        <init-param>  
            <param-name>service</param-name>  
            <param-value>http://localhost:9080/cas1</param-value>  
        </init-param>  
    </filter> 
    <filter-mapping>  
        <filter-name>CAS Validation Filter</filter-name>  
        <url-pattern>/*</url-pattern>  
    </filter-mapping>   

    <filter>  
        <filter-name>CAS HttpServletRequest Wrapper Filter</filter-name>  
        <filter-class>org.jasig.cas.client.util.HttpServletRequestWrapperFilter</filter-class>  
    </filter>  
    <filter-mapping>  
        <filter-name>CAS HttpServletRequest Wrapper Filter</filter-name>  
        <url-pattern>/*</url-pattern>  
    </filter-mapping>
```

Comment: hey I have tried the same.. but still its not logging out.. any changes needs to be done cas webapp ?

Comment: what is these tags and what this urls refers ? 
<init-param>  
            <param-name>service</param-name>  
            <param-value>http://localhost:9080/cas1</param-value>  
        </init-param>

Comment: That parameter refers to the cas client application. Have a look at https://wiki.jasig.org/display/CASC/Configuring+the+Jasig+CAS+Client+for+Java+in+the+web.xml

Comment: @codependent For me too as per the server logs its sending logout requests. But the client sessions were not invalidated. Do you have any SAML dependencies in client? Did you get any errors in your client application? Do you exactly know how does this single signout working? I mean the work flow.